# Merge query in snowflake gives incorrect count of data

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am downloading two files and adding them to staging area to temp table then merging them to main table.
But I am getting incorrect count of date:

```
    def load_snowflake_table(self, directory):
        try:
            self.snowflake_client.run("ALTER SESSION SET TIMEZONE = 'UTC';")
            self.stage_name = f"{self.sf_temp_table}_{self.snowflake_client.generate_random_string()}"
            create_stage = f"CREATE TEMPORARY STAGE {self.stage_name} COMMENT = 'TEMPORARY STAGE FOR {self.sf_temp_table} DATA LOAD'"
            self.snowflake_client.run(create_stage)
            logger.info("Temporary stage created.")

            self.snowflake_client.run(f"put file://{directory}/* @{self.stage_name} PARALLEL=4")
            logger.info(f"Successfully uploaded all files to staging area.")

            self.snowflake_client.run(
                f"COPY INTO {self.sf_temp_table}  FROM @{self.stage_name} PURGE = TRUE MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = "
                f"'CASE_INSENSITIVE'  FILE_FORMAT "
                f"= (TYPE = 'AVRO')")
            logger.info(f"Successfully copied the files data temporary table {self.sf_temp_table}")

            sf_query = f"SELECT COUNT(*) from {self.sf_temp_table}"
            logger.info(sf_query)
            sf_count = self.snowflake_client.run(sf_query).fetchall()
            sf_count = sf_count[0][0]
            print("=====================")
            print(sf_count)

            merge_query = self.form_merge_query(self.COLUMNS)

            logger.info(f"Executing merge query: {merge_query}")
            self.snowflake_client.run(merge_query)

            logger.info("Truncating temporary table")
            self.snowflake_client.run(f"TRUNCATE TABLE IF EXISTS {self.sf_temp_table}")

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Error Loading to Snowflake{e}".format(e=e))
            raise e
        finally:
            self.snowflake_client.run(f"DROP STAGE IF EXISTS {self.stage_name}")
            logger.info(f"Dropped temporary stage {self.stage_name}")
```

The count in first file was 135839 and the same count was in temporary table and on second file count was 135687 and same count was on temporary table. Hence the count in final table should be 271,526 but this is coming out to be incorrect.

All the records are unique on primary key combination.

My merge query is:

```
MERGE
INTO
MERGETEST
USING 
(SELECT $1 CHANNELGROUPING, $2 CLIENTID, $3 CUSTOMDIMENSIONS, $4 DATE, $5 DEVICE, $6 FULLVISITORID,
$7 GEONETWORK, $8 SOCIALENGAGEMENTTYPE, $9 TOTALS,
$10 TRAFFICSOURCE, $11 VISITID, $12 VISITNUMBER, $13 VISITSTARTTIME, $14 APPINFO, $15 CONTENTGROUP,      
$16 HITS_CUSTOMDIMENSIONS, $17 CUSTOMMETRICS,$18 CUSTOMVARIABLES, $19 DATASOURCE, $20 ECOMMERCEACTION,
$21 EVENTINFO, $22 EXCEPTIONINFO, $23 EXPERIMENT, $24 HITNUMBER
FROM T_SESSIONS)
as TEST_SESSIONS
ON MERGETEST.FULLVISITORID = TEST_SESSIONS.FULLVISITORID and MERGETEST.VISITID = TEST_SESSIONS.VISITID and
MERGETEST.VISITSTARTTIME = TEST_SESSIONS.VISITSTARTTIME and MERGETEST.HITNUMBER = TEST_SESSIONS.HITNUMBER
WHEN
NOT
MATCHED and 
THEN
INSERT(CHANNELGROUPING,CLIENTID,CUSTOMDIMENSIONS,DATE,DEVICE,FULLVISITORID,GEONETWORK,SOCIALENGAGEMENTTYPE,TOTALS,
       TRAFFICSOURCE,VISITID,VISITNUMBER,VISITSTARTTIME,APPINFO,CONTENTGROUP,HITS_CUSTOMDIMENSIONS,CUSTOMMETRICS,
       CUSTOMVARIABLES,DATASOURCE,ECOMMERCEACTION,EVENTINFO,EXCEPTIONINFO,EXPERIMENT,HITNUMBER)
VALUES
(TEST_SESSIONS.CHANNELGROUPING,TEST_SESSIONS.CLIENTID,TEST_SESSIONS.CUSTOMDIMENSIONS,TEST_SESSIONS.DATE,
TEST_SESSIONS.DEVICE,TEST_SESSIONS.FULLVISITORID,TEST_SESSIONS.GEONETWORK,TEST_SESSIONS.SOCIALENGAGEMENTTYPE,
TEST_SESSIONS.TOTALS,TEST_SESSIONS.TRAFFICSOURCE,TEST_SESSIONS.VISITID,TEST_SESSIONS.VISITNUMBER,
TEST_SESSIONS.VISITSTARTTIME,TEST_SESSIONS.APPINFO,TEST_SESSIONS.CONTENTGROUP,TEST_SESSIONS.HITS_CUSTOMDIMENSIONS,
TEST_SESSIONS.CUSTOMMETRICS,TEST_SESSIONS.CUSTOMVARIABLES,TEST_SESSIONS.DATASOURCE,TEST_SESSIONS.ECOMMERCEACTION,
TEST_SESSIONS.EVENTINFO,TEST_SESSIONS.EXCEPTIONINFO,TEST_SESSIONS.EXPERIMENT,TEST_SESSIONS.HITNUMBER);
```

**All my rows are unique on FULLVISITORID, VISITID, VISITSTARTTIME and HITNUMBER combination.** But still I am not getting the correct number of rows.

Till the temporary table I got what was expected. Is there something wrong with the approach or my merge query?

Answer (score 0):

File/table one: 135,839
File/table two: 135,687
Expected: 135,839 + 135,687 = 271,526

The assumption that their merged version has to be the sum may not be the case when they share the same keys between two tables.

Sample scenario (two rows + one row)

```
(FULLVISITORID, VISITID, VISITSTARTTIME, HITNUMBER, ...)
1, 1, 2021-01-01, 1, ...
2, 2, 2021-01-01, 2, ...
```

Other table:

```
(FULLVISITORID, VISITID, VISITSTARTTIME, HITNUMBER, ...)
1, 1, 2021-01-01, 1, ...
```

After the merge that is performing INSERT only the output will be 2 rows and not 3.

```
(FULLVISITORID, VISITID, VISITSTARTTIME, HITNUMBER, ...)
1, 1, 2021-01-01, 1, ...
2, 2, 2021-01-01, 2, ...
```

---

To find the overlap `INTERSECT` could be used:

```
SELECT $6 FULLVISITORID, $11 VISITID, $13 VISITSTARTTIME, $24 HITNUMBER 
FROM T_SESSIONS
INTERSECT
SELECT FULLVISITORID, VISITID, VISITSTARTTIME, HITNUMBER 
FROM MERGETEST;
```

Comment: All the rows are unique
```select FULLVISITORID, VISITID, VISITSTARTTIME, HITNUMBER, count(*) from Source_table group by  FULLVISITORID, VISITID, VISITSTARTTIME, HITNUMBER having count(*) > 1
```
 I get no rows

Comment: ```
select FULLVISITORID, VISITID, VISITSTARTTIME, HITNUMBER, count(*) from Source_table group by FULLVISITORID, VISITID, VISITSTARTTIME, HITNUMBER having count(*) = 1
```
@Lukasz Szozda

I get 271,526